# Ruby setup in docker

Tags: ruby, docker, rake, bundler, rbenv

I need to get a docker image with ruby>=2.5 installed, and then run `bundle exec rake test` in the container. I know that could be simply accomplished by using the official [docker ruby image](https://hub.docker.com/_/ruby) but due to licensing restrictions I cannot do that.

So, what I have to work with is an [image with rbenv pre-configured](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/ruby-docker). After much trial and error I've arrived at the following dockerfile:

```
FROM launcher.gcr.io/google/ruby:latest

RUN rbenv install 2.5.7
RUN rbenv rehash
RUN rbenv global 2.5.7

COPY ./ /my-app
WORKDIR /my-app
RUN gem install bundler
RUN bundle install
ENTRYPOINT bundle exec rake test
```

I build it with `docker build -f dockerfile.tests . -t tests` and then run with `docker run -i tests` and what I get is:

```
/usr/bin/env: 'ruby2.5': No such file or directory
```

Any ideas of what could be wrong here? Thank you!

ps. I've tried the same with RVM and the end result was exactly the same error. Also tried (initially) to install ruby 2.5 with `apt install` but the latest version available via apt is 2.3.

Comment: `rbenv` within Docker is redundant. Just use the image that comes with Ruby 2.5.7 and then you are good to go.

Answer (score 1):

If you wish to avoid the official Ruby image (which I do as well, since it is too big), you can easily build an Alpine based image from scratch, no RVM or rbenv needed.

[This is my Dockerfile](https://github.com/DannyBen/docker-alpine-ruby/blob/master/Dockerfile):

```
FROM alpine:3.10

ENV BUILD_PACKAGES bash curl curl-dev ruby-dev build-base
ENV RUBY_PACKAGES \
  ruby ruby-io-console ruby-irb \
  ruby-json ruby-etc ruby-bigdecimal ruby-rdoc \
  libffi-dev zlib-dev
ENV TERM=linux
ENV PS1 "\n\n>> ruby \W \$ "

RUN apk --no-cache add $BUILD_PACKAGES $RUBY_PACKAGES

RUN echo 'gem: --no-document' > /etc/gemrc && \
    gem install bundler

RUN gem update --system

RUN bundle config --global silence_root_warning 1

CMD bash
```

You might even not need all the alpine packages I am installing here. 
For me, I added these over time as I saw that without them, some native gems fail to build properly.